# Object.defineProperty() inside the getter

Tags: javascript

I've a scenario where I need to modify a `property` of a `class` using `Object.defineProperty()`. I know it can be done through the `get()` of the `descriptor`.

If you see the example below, I'm trying to return a `function` which when called will return a value from `this`.

My question is, do I need to `define` that `property` again for the `this` object? Is it necessary? If yes, why?

When I define a property to a class, `this` will also reflect the same right?

I came through [this](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator/blob/master/src/index.js#L80-L88) and I'm curious to know why he is doing this.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.h = 'hello world'
  }
  hello() {}
}

const des = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(A.prototype, 'hello')

Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'hello', {
  configurable: true,
  get: function(){
    //is this necessary
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'hello', {
      configurable: true,
      value: () => this.h,
    })
    //                      
    return () => this.h
  }
})

const n = new A()

console.log(n.hello())
```

Comment: Why not just define that property outside of getter? Your current code will define new property every time the prototype is accessed.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 Outside the getter you won't get `this`

Comment: You won't get `this` if you use arrow functions. Instead, you should use standard functions, so you can bind them to your instance (or prototype) and access instance's `this`.

Comment: Why don't you directly return `this.h` ? https://jsfiddle.net/str9ro03/

Comment: @Cristy That is my question. Even I'm returning `this.h`. I came through [this](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator/blob/master/src/index.js#L80-L88) and I was curious to know why he is doing this.

Comment: @PraneshRavi They are creating a bound function, not returning a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why that person is doing this. I probably wouldn't do it. But if your question is whether there is a difference in doing it or not, the answer is yes.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.h = 'hello world'
  }
  hello() {}
}
const des = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(A.prototype, 'hello')
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'hello1', {
  configurable: true,
  get: function() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'hello1', {
      configurable: true,
      value: () => this.h,
    });                 
    return () => this.h;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'hello2', {
  configurable: true,
  get: function() {
    return () => this.h;
  }
});
const n = new A()
console.log(n.hello1); // () => this.h       OK
console.log(n.hello2); // () => this.h       OK
Object.setPrototypeOf(n, null);
console.log(n.hello1); // () => this.h       Still OK
console.log(n.hello2); // undefined          Oops!
```

It's also possible that calling a getter may be more expensive than reading a data property.

Comment: So, you're saying when I do `Object.defineProperty(this, key)`, it means the key is bound to `this` regardless of the `prototype`.

Comment: BTW, when you meant *"It's also possible that calling a getter may be more expensive than reading a data property.*, it is not possible to get `this`(the context of the class) out of the `getter` or the `setter` ryt?

Comment: @PraneshRavi Well, you can access it in the constructor

Comment: Can you add an example if possible?

Comment: @PraneshRavi `class A { constructor() {  this.h = 'hello world'; this.hello = () => this.h } }`

Comment: I got it. But I want to do it via `defineProperty`.

Comment: `class A { constructor() { this.h = 'hello world'; Object.defineProperty(this, "hello", {value: () => this.h }) } }`